# What CQC moves can you do in Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Metal Gear Solid 5: The Phantom Pain, I am aware of being able to dive, and perform combos, hold-ups and interrogations.

What other moves can you do using CQC?

Comment: Depends on your definition of cool..

Comment: Below average temperature?

Comment: I'm voting to close because the initial wording of this question is very opinion-based. However, it could be salvaged by changing it into something like "What sorts of moves can you perform in MGSV?". I'll leave it to the asker to edit it if they wish.

Comment: @Timelord64 That edit was not acceptable.  You changed the intent of the question.  Even to salvage a question, that's not what edits are meant to do; it must be done by the asker.

Comment: @Frank, considering the removal of **a single word** to be to far against intent, when that single word is the sole argument for the questions closure, sounds lot more like the "elitist laziness" argument of "you don't know how to ask a question, go away" then an argument of how act on the Arqade. It asks if an edit can make the question salvageable, in the close review, itself.

Comment: @Frank I disagree 100%. The question is asking if you can do any cool melee moves other than a few. Revision 2, in essence, asks if you can do any melee moves other than the few. All revision 2 did was shift the burden to decide which of the possible moves were "cool" to the asker.

Comment: @Unionhawk Which was the primary intent of the asker.  Changing it from asking what cool moves you can do, to what moves you *can* do, isn't what's being asked.

Comment: @Timelord64 That word changes the question entirely.  It's not about word count that changes.  Edits are for **clarification** and cleanup.  *Not* changing what's being asked.  Edits can salvage a question, especially for the Unclear close reason, but that's not license to change what's being asked.

Comment: I think @Unionhawk words it best. Were trying to address the problem, rather then delete it out of the context of a single word. The answer still effectively provides OP with the best answer we could possibly give, as it ultimately comes down to their interpretation of what is cool, and what is not. Intent goes a long way, but ultimately, its fair to assume there was more intent to have their question answered, then to be deliberately shown somebody else's interpretation of "cool". If the rules appear black and white against this, then perhaps it is the rules we need to address, instead?

Comment: @Timelord64 I think ultimately, there are two different interpretations at work here. I see it as being, "Hey, some of these moves I can do are really cool! What other moves are cool?", and you are probably seeing it as, "Hey, here are the moves I can do. Are there any I'm missing?", I think.  I'm guessing that's where the disagreement is coming in, and is probably a good reason to ask for clarification from the asker.

Comment: As a sidenote, casting aspersions on someone else's motivation for site curation is neither here nor there; it has no bearing on the question in play, and doesn't help your argument.  We're all here to try to make the site better, muddling along together.  Might not always get it, but a good faith assumption goes a long way.

Comment: Well, in an effort to prevent a procedural close vote, I'm going to rollback to revision 2. @mugen2099, if you have any objections, you are always free to revert to the original. I don't personally feel this question is opinion-based in its current state, however, sometimes people get hung up on words like "cool" and "best".

Comment: I do see the point that Frank is trying to make, it is just my opinion that it is counter productive to this site. @mugen2099, a good answer to "what CQC moves are there" could contain a short video demonstrating each technique, for you to interpret what moves you like and don't like. Once I have access to a better computer, it won't be hard for me to make such a video, but until then, a list of available moves will still allow you to perform them in-game, to see them for yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### **Combos**

You can do a combo up to five hits long by tapping the CQC button in rapid succession. Three hits will knock your average guard from behind and five hits will knock them out from the front. This is the most effective in terms of stun "damage" and it will knock your target out for the longest. It's not completely quiet, so be wary of using it when other guards are nearby. Guards that are aware of you will try to stab you with a knife or hit you with their rifle butt if you come within melee range. If you press the CQC button, Snake will deflect their attack and do his combo normally. Just be sure not to be slow about it.

**Disarm**

In addition to the combo, you can hold right-click (the button you use to ready your weapon, not sure what it is on consoles) in the *middle* of a combo to instead take the enemy's weapon and instantly perform a hold-up. This is very useful during [SUBSISTENCE] missions.

### **Holds**

You can perform a *chokehold* by holding the CQC button when you walk up to an enemy. This will allow you to choke out, kill, or interrogate the target. Choking out is effective at keeping your target unconscious, second only in duration to the full striking combo. Tapping the CQC button rapidly during a choke-out will choke out the target faster, up to roughly half the time it takes just holding the button. You can let go of the CQC button briefly and re-click it and a movement direction together to perform a throw out of the hold.

**Up-and-Over and Corner Holds**

If you are crouched behind a half-wall, such as stacked sandbags, you can quickly drag a guard on the other side of the wall over to your side and put them in a hold with the CQC button. You have to be directly on the other side of the wall from the guard. If you're standing around a corner and a guard walks up to the corner, you can grab them and hold them securely behind the corner. Just remain still in cover on the corner of the wall and hit the CQC button when the guard walks close enough to issue the prompt.

### **Throws**

Pressing a movement direction and tapping the CQC button at the same time will allow you to instantly perform a knock-out throw. This only leaves them unconscious for a few seconds, however, so be sure to follow-up with something else. This move is fast, and you can chain it together with other guards nearby (you won't be alerted while chaining the moves together as far as I can tell, even when reflex mode is off), so it is effective if you've been spotted by nearby guards and they're about to sound the alert.

**Into Walls**

If the guard is close to a wall, and you are positioned appropriately and you press the appropriate direction as you push the CQC button, you will throw them face-first into a wall or other large object. This will knock them out longer, but it is still not a safe long-term option.

### **Hold-Up**

Hold-ups are performed when you point a firearm at an unaware guard from point-blank range (three meters or less). Snake will automatically whisper "Don't. Move." and the guard will timidly place their weapon on the ground and raise their hands. Pressing the call button will give you the same options that you would normally get during a CQC hold interrogation. In addition, you can tell the guard to "get down," which will effectively neutralize them indefinitely. However, other guards will help them back up and up the alert level. Also, if you go on combat alert, they'll get back up and retrieve their weapon.

> Sometimes, holding up a guard will not give you access to the regular holdup commands - this is because the guard is planning to turn the tables on you. They'll reach for a knife and then spin around and slash you with it. If they hit you, you'll be knocked back and they'll have time to raise an alert. If you can't immediately interrogate a held-up guard, give 'em the old grab and slam for safety

Thanks @twobugs.

### **Trip**

If you are prone and press the CQC button, Snake will perform an arm sweep that will trip enemies. This is not a very effective move overall and it's best to avoid it. It has a very limited application, which is that you've been spotted while prone and you need to buy yourself a couple of seconds. Once you've tripped the guard that spotted you, be sure to stand up or crouch so that you can perform proper CQC.

> If you're laying on your back (such as from being slashed from failed hold up) pressing Attack will perform a sweeping kick that ends with you crouched. The effect is similar to the arm sweep. After you knock the guard down you can Aim to perform a hold up.

Thanks @Ampersand. You can turn over by using the roll action (hold sprint and move left and right while prone) or by going prone, then using a weapon to aim behind you -- that will cause Snake to flip over so he can aim in that direction.

### **The Boot**

Standing or crouching over enemies that are tripped or unconscious and hitting the CQC button will kick them while they're down. If they're unconscious or sleeping, this will wake them. If they're not, they'll fall unconscious. I'm not completely sure how long unconsciousness induced in this way lasts.

### **Goomba'ing**

Landing on a guard's head from above will render them unconscious instantly.

### Shimmying/Ladder Throws

> ...you can pull people down to knock them out when they're standing at the top of a ladder you're climbing [by pressing the CQC button]

Thanks @user2357112.

Comment: In addition, the regular five-hit combo attack has some different animation variations depending on the context (generally when you are in a combat alert, you'll get some different knife- or gun- redirection animations out of the combo depending on what the guard was doing).

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about that. Guards that are aware of you will try to stab you with a knife or hit you with their rifle butt if you come within melee range. If you press the CQC button, Snake will deflect their attack and do his combo normally. Just be sure not to be slow about it.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to wake up enemies i knocked out to interrogate, does this work on sleeping enemies or just ko'd ones?

Comment: Yes, it also works on sleeping enemies. Waking up a guard for interrogation is something I do very frequently.

Comment: Sometimes, holding up a guard will not give you access to the regular holdup commands - this is because the guard is planning to turn the tables on you. They'll reach for a knife and then spin around and slash you with it. If they hit you, you'll be knocked back and they'll have time to raise an alert. If you can't immediately interrogate a held-up guard, give 'em the old grab and slam for safety.

Comment: Wow, that has never happened to me. I'll add that to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: If things like landing on people are going into the list, then it's probably worth mentioning that you can pull people down to knock them out when they're standing at the top of a ladder you're climbing.

Comment: If you're laying on your back (such as from being slashed from failed hold up) pressing Attack will perform a sweeping kick that ends with you crouched. The effect is similar to the arm sweep. After you knock the guard down you can Aim to perform a hold up.

Comment: The editor is correct about the 3-hit vs 5-hit combo, I suppose... I never CQC combo enemies from the front, if they end up facing me and spotting me I always just panic and throw! Lol.